# Specific value in contour lines plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, contour

I would have to specify the line value but with a different contour scale, i.e. the lines of this figure:

contour plot with 0.1 size

[image: contour plot with 0.1 size]

But with the scale of this one:

contour plot with 0.01 size

[image: contour plot with 0.01 size]

I am using this data:

```
#head(TRW_Gamir)
coef_spei1_TRW.month TRW_Gamir  value
AJAN                 A1         0.41524874
BFEB                 A1         0.04231552
CMAR                 A1         0.17675466
DAPR                 A1         0.01627214
EMAY                 A1         0.38097442
JJUN                 A1         0.32739887
GJUL                 A1         0.02970376
HAUG                 A1         0.01985717
ISEP                 A1         -0.18429869
JOCT                 A1         -0.07569144
KNov                 A1         0.20323849
LDec                 A1         0.15099979
AJAN                 B2         0.43410092
BFEB                 B2         0.34736024
CMAR                 B2         0.14635750
DAPR                 B2         0.14878060
EMAY                 B2         0.25183884
JJUN                 B2         0.45849358
GJUL                 B2         0.28952867
HAUG                 B2         0.04212230
ISEP                 B2         -0.17024980
JOCT                 B2         -0.12148804
KNov                 B2         0.10255282
LDec                 B2         0.24201543
```

With the code for the first image:

```
plot_ly(data = TRW_Gamir, x = ~TRW_Gamir, y=~coef_spei1_TRW.month, z=~value, 
        type = "contour", colorscale ="Jet" , showscale= TRUE, 
        line= list(width=0.5, color="black"), 
        contours = list(start = -0.3, end = 0.6, size = 0.1, showlabels = T))
```

And for the second:

```
plot_ly(data = TRW_Gamir, x = ~TRW_Gamir, y=~coef_spei1_TRW.month, z=~value, 
        type = "contour", colorscale ="Jet" , showscale= TRUE, 
        line= list(width=0.01, color="black"), 
        contours = list(start = -0.3, end = 0.6, size = 00.1, showlabels = F))
```

The final figure has to be like this:

[image: final figure]

Comment: You wanna show the lines from the first graph on the second graph?

Comment: first graph lines